# Calculating the infinite series $1-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\frac19-\frac1{11}\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

My main question is the one in the title, however I was also wondering, in general when it comes to infinite series, how can you find out whether the series converges to a value or not? And can you tell if there will be something strange about it? What I mean is that you would expect the sum of all natural numbers to be infinity, but it is -1/12. Is there a way of knowing if something like this will happen?

Sorry for the ton of questions! And thank you for any answers :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80

Comment: To answer one of them, the series of the title of your question is convergent due to [this test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Alternating_series_test).

Comment: There is usually a lecture in the math curriculum of any university which covers convergence of series. If you are not studying math at university you could try learning it on Khan Academy.

Comment: Regarding the sum of all natural numbers - it does not converge to -1/12, it diverges to infinite (so there's nothing "strange" about it). (What you're referring to is the Ramanujan summation)

Comment: What do you exactly mean by *you would expect the sum of all natural numbers to be infinity, but it is -1/12*? There are methods to sum a divergent series, while the partial sum do not converge, but it's a different matter than converging series like the one in title.

Comment: Sorry if I have caused confusion with regards to converging and diverging series- I wasn't sure whether this one would be converging or diverging because I would also expect the harmonic series to converge, but it does not.

Comment: @lemon I looked up Ramanujan summation and am slightly confused- it seems to simply be for convenience (quoting wikipedia "for assigning a value to infinite divergent series") rather than having a real meaning. However I used this sum when finding the sum between two parallel plates in a vacuum, and I know that the Casimir effect is experimentally verified. I'm unsure now as to why assigning -1/12 to the sum of natural numbers can be used in physics or have any real meaning.

Comment: @21joanna12 Welcome to the world of [regularisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(physics)) and [renormalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization).

Answer (score 14):

Recall that
$$
\frac{1}{1+x^2}=1-x^2+x^4+\cdots
$$
If you integrate from $0$ to $1$
$$
\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2} dx& =\int_0^11-x^2+x^4-x^6+\cdots\,dx\\
& =1-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\cdots
\end{align}
$$ but $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2} dx=\arctan 1-\arctan 0 = \frac\pi4, $$
then
$$
1-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\frac19-\cdots=\frac\pi4
$$

Comment: Hahaha- I was initially trying to calculate what the [pi/2 x integral of 1/(1+x^2) from -pi/4 to pi/4] was and this led me to formulate that series! :) I'm trying to find the integarl without knowing that it is arctan1....

Answer (score 4):

**An other way:**
$$\arctan x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}x^n.$$
if $|x|<1$. Morevoer $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$$
is an [Alternating series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series), then it converge. By [Abel's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) you can conclude that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}=\arctan(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+ \dots =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$$

Have you got taught the Dirichlet's criterion?

Use this,and you prove that your infinite sum converges.

Comment: It should be put as a comment !

Comment: Why should I put it as a comment???

Comment: because it's a remark and not an answer !

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, but I'll look up the proof- thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\left( { - 1} \right)^n }}{{2n + 1}}}  = \frac{\pi }{4}$$

Comment: Your answer is not constructive. You have to explain why we have this equality !